# How can I create a wxSpinCtrlDouble control in wxCrafter in CodeLite?

Tags: wxwidgets, codelite

I have a project in which I need to let my user enter a floating-point number in the range [0.0 .. 4.99].  I can let them enter the number via a spin control or a text box.

wxWidgets provides a control called wxSpinCtrlDouble.  I think it will do what I want it to do.

But since I am using wxCrafter inside CodeLite, and wxCrafter does not offer wxSpinCtrlDouble, I am not sure how to add a wxSpinCtrlDouble control to my project.  If I hand-made a wxSpinCtrlDouble control inside wxcrafter.cpp, wouldn't wxCrafter erase my code the next time it built wxcrafter.cpp?

How can I add the wxSpinCtrlDouble control to my project using wxCrafter?

I am using the following software versions.

```
CodeLite:  9.2.0
gcc:       4.9.3
wxCrafter: 2.5
wxWidgets: 3.1.0
```

I did post a message on the CodeLite forum asking this question on October 6, 2016, but as of November 30, 2016, there were no answers. https://forums.codelite.org/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=3495

Thanks.

Colleen

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wxSpinCtrl inside a wxCrafter tool, generate the code and then change the code to use the control you want.

Comment: Oh, that's a great idea! I'll try it. Thanks, @Igor!